# My Google Business Accounts Location Reviews Class Missing (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-developers-console, google-my-business-api, google-reviews

I am updating our google api client services to new ones. I am using the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services) for it.

I am looking for this class `ListReviewsResponse` with alias `Google_Service_MyBusiness_ListReviewsResponse` so I can fetch the account reviews but can't see it in the mentioned repository.

Where can I find this or is it moved somewhere? TIA

Edit: added more tags, added edit

Answer (score 0):

I just found this in the issues tab. The endpoint is not yet deprecated that's why it has no v1 version. Here's the [comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/issues/340#issuecomment-1093307953) that suggested it. Thanks!

Edit: So I will leave the old code be.